# I have error in android with Kotlin

Tags: android, compiler-errors, kotlin

Why this error?

```
    09-12 16:36:31.502 1886-1886/com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
 main Process: com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation, 
PID: 1886 kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String 

at com.getloction.nourmedhat.smartgate.getlocation.All_Station$onCreate$2.onDataChange(All_Station.kt:56) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: You tried to use `null` with a `String`. If that seems lacklustre, it's because there's zero code or anything to go from. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @BakaWaii same user, same zero description

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String

You try to cast object which null to String. See line 56 in All_Station.kt

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass **null** to **Non-null** String type.

For example, if you have String like this.

`var myString: String = ""`

In runtime, if you try to set it as null it will cause you the error.

You have to make the specific string to nullable type like the below example:

```
var myString: String? = null
```